# What questions to ask in user interview to create better empathy map?

Tags: user-research, quantitative-analysis

After an exhausted research in the topic of Empathy Map, I understand the critical parts of the most famous maps like 4 quadrants, and Xplaner(gamestorming book) v 1.0 and 2.0 types.

They are met on that better to conduct user interviews to gain more sensitive result.

But all resources have missing an important part, What type of question to ask user on the interview related to empathy map, type of information we are looking to feed this map?

Comment: The question you need to ask yourself: how expensive is a local designer: more or less than the time it will take to understand and perform their function within this project?

Answer (score 1):

Question: What method do you intend to use? Will you be doing face-to-face interviews or observations in context?

Adding observation is key because you can actually watch people trying to accomplish their goals in the context where they will do it. Behaviors are always more true than words so you can actually see what they do. In some contexts it can be a challenge but there are still ways to do it.

Regardless, you will want to formulate a few questions ahead of time. If you are trying to understand the customer in general and what they care about, use open-ended questions. Suggestions below.

1. How often do you do [goal you care about]?
2. Thinking about the most recent time you did [goal], what was your reason for doing it?
3. Can you walk me through how you did [goal] the most recent time you did it? (Use this question to dig in. They will likely tell you a lot but they will leave a lot out because they assume you know it or they forgot. Listen carefully and find key points to say, "tell me more about Y.")
4. What's most important for you when you're doing [goal]?
5. What would you say is most difficult when doing [goal]?

These questions should elicit a lot of qualitative data about their experience and desired outcomes. There should be aspects that are seeing, doing, and feeling. Categorize the data and use it to fill in the Empathy Map. If you can add observation, you will have better insights into what they see and do based on their actual behavior.

Hope this information was helpful!